# My tabBar does not appear complete in the screen

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

My tabBar does not appear complete in the screen in my application. I have created with this code:

```
- (void) setupTabBar {

    YPProfileViewController *vc1 = [[YPProfileViewController alloc] init];
    vc1.title = @"FIRST";
    vc1.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

    YPProjectListViewController *vc2 = [[YPProjectListViewController alloc] init];
    vc2.title = @"SECOND";
    vc2.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    UITabBarController *tabBar = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    tabBar.viewControllers = @[vc1,vc2];
    tabBar.selectedIndex   = 1;

    [tabBar.view setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
    [tabBar willMoveToParentViewController:self];
    [self addChildViewController:tabBar];
    [tabBar didMoveToParentViewController:self];
    [self.view addSubview:tabBar.view];

}
```

This is my problem : [image: TabBar is not getting resize]

Comment: Where is this method being called?

Comment: use this line before you call your "setupTabBar" method "self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = TRUE;"

Comment: The method is being called in viewDidLoad method. And I have used "self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = TRUE;" but if I use this I lose the navigation Bar, but I need the navigation bar to get back to the View before.